# Using today's date in filename when loading variables from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a JavaScript file containing variables into an HTML file. I have managed to include the file so far by using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='C:/Documents/Site/Stage1/Live/2020-03-15/Stage1-Answers-2020-03-15.js';></script>
```

However, I would like the program to use today's date automatically. So far I have the variable todayDate:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetDate() {
  var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
};
</script>
```

How can I include the variable todayDate in the JavaScript filepath?

Comment: You may have to add the script tag by manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the date with PHP, or alternatively, if you're running it without a server, you could load it with JavaScript by using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'C:/Documents/Site/Stage1/Live/'+todayDate+'/Stage1-Answers-'+todayDate+'.js';
script.onload = function() {
  console.log(CorrectAnswer1[0]);
}
document.head.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

This will generate the HTML you provided dynamically.

Comment: `src = 'C:/Documents/Site/Stage1/Live/'+todayDate+'/Stage1-Answers-'+todayDate+'.js'`
and subfolder i assume

Comment: Thank you for answering but I haven't been able to get it to work. Can you see anything wrong in the attached picture? Thanks again! https://i.imgur.com/uy0qVvp.png

Comment: @Reckless The script is not loaded instantly, so it won't be able to access the variables until loading has completed

Comment: @Reckless Try the change that I have added above (`script.onload = ...`) and see if it works.

Comment: That has sorted the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve without any extra function and variable as shown below, because whatever you are doing in your function can be directly append into your url itself.

```
<script>
    <script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='C:/Documents/Site/Stage1/Live/" + new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10) + "/Stage1-Answers-" + new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)+ ".js'><\/script>");</script>
</script>
```